# Request Headers Authorization is not found

Tags: node.js, authorization, request-headers

I am trying to create session for user but request headers authorization is missing from request headers.
Middleware/auth.js
code:

```
const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.headers);
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
        const isCustomAuth = token.length < 500;
        let decodedData;
        if(token && isCustomAuth){
            // local token
            decodedData = jwt.verify(token, "secret");
            req.userId = decodedData?.id;
        } else {
            // google token
            decodedData = jwt.decode(token);
            req.userId = decodedData?.sub;
        }
        next();
    }
```

Result of request headers and the error

```
{
  'x-forwarded-host': 'localhost:3000',        
  'x-forwarded-proto': 'http',
  'x-forwarded-port': '3000',
  'x-forwarded-for': '127.0.0.1',
  cookie: 'g_state={"i_l":0}; connect.sid=s%3AFRPdteq7r6JOP-nebD6ZYM-rN58f5lUX.J0vCo1Q3w3s3%2Fpm5f58Yven2c3eKj2jGJCnc7xvFles',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',      
  referer: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  origin: 'http://localhost:5000/',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/107.0.1418.62',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*', 
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Microsoft Edge";v="107", "Chromium";v="107", "Not=A?Brand";v="24"',
  'content-length': '370690',
  connection: 'close',
  host: 'localhost:5000'
}
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
```